# Send mail with Python App Engine turns norwegian characters into <?>

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I am using

from google.appengine.api import mail

To send email on app engine running python. When i checked the sent mail it could not handle the norwegian characters åæø. All åæø characters are turned into  when reading the mail in gmail.

Below is the mail sending method called (removed some content).

```
mail.send_mail(sender="ExphilApp <xxxxx@gmail.com>",
                  to=email,
                  subject="Velkommen til ExPhil-appen",
                  body="""
    Hei {0}!
Takk for at du registerte deg til ExPhil-appen. Ditt brukernavn er {1}. 
For mer info, se www.exphilapp.no

    Hilsen Håkon

    """.format(name,username))
```

File encoding is:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

The special case here is that i use the triple """ quote mark to construct the string as well as .format to insert users name and username. How can i make the string work with norwegian characters åæø?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling unicode literals for representing Norwegian characters with:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

BTW, it seems that you are hitting a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=639)

Comment: Getting this error on that one:
line 286, in get
    &quot;&quot;&quot;.format(name,username).encode(&quot;utf-8&quot;))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
</pre>
  </body>

Comment: thanks for updating answer. With the added unicode and removal .encode("utf-8")
Still get the error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 138: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Looks like you are hitting a known bug with the AppEngine mailer: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=639

Comment: Thanks for the help, googled a bit and found a workaround involving future literals module. If you update your answer i can accept that one instead of my own :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

to the start of the file.